# HTML/CSS: How to make the sidebar and content follow each other

Tags: html, css, height, sidebar

I need a sidebar and a content area. I want to have equal height for both sections. So if I want to specify a background color for the sidebar, it will follow the content area even if the sidebar's contents are not as tall as the content section and vice versa. I want to make this in pure HTML and CSS only, so no javascript tricks.

Comment: You can do it without javascript: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: Yeah, 20 times the amount of html / style code and a guarantee that you'll be working on just this part for days trying to figure out why it doesn't work in some of the browsers when a table tag was built for exactly this problem...

Comment: This is suboptimal because it involves unnecessary nested `<div>` elements and some pretty ugly CSS tricks, but it's better than Chis' table-based solution.

Comment: @Chris: The `<table>` **element** was not built to solve this problem. It was built to display tabular data.

Comment: @You: citation please?  Mine is: http://www.barrypearson.co.uk/articles/layout_tables/history.htm

Comment: @Chris: See every HTML specification ever.

Comment: @You: like this one on w3.org which supports tables for layout: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-tables-960123  says "The HTML table model has evolved from studies of existing SGML tables models, the treatment of tables in common word processing packages, and looking at a wide range of tabular layout in magazines, books and other paper-based documents. ... This feature has been very important to the success of HTML to date. "

Comment: Are HTML tables bad because they break separation of concerns? Or is it because of security? I get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way of doing this in a cross browser fashion is with tables.

As content is added to the sidebar cell below, it will force the entire row to expand which in turn will force the contentArea cell to expand as well.  You can style those individually with css.

```
<style>
  #sideBar { vertical-align:top;}
  #contentArea { vertical-align:top;}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="sideBar">SideBar</td>
    <td id="contentArea">content area</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes I know this too, but for example when I write more content on the sidebar the content part will be on the middle of the page, I mean in the middle of the sidebar. Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: See the update.  if you apply a vertical-align: top to the cells, then the content will align to the top of the cell.

Comment: Don't do this. Tables are for tabular data, not layouting.

Comment: use style="vertical-align:top" for every <td>

Comment: @You: religious adherence to dogma results in pain for everyone.  And tables were indeed meant for layout when they were first introduced.  You might want to check this out: http://www.barrypearson.co.uk/articles/layout_tables/history.htm

Comment: I don't have any problem with tables, if you check out twitters layout you will see that they are using tables too to reach the same effect.

Comment: Ok thanks very much! 'Vertical-align:top' works cool! I used this table layout before, but the the content in the middle was not good so now works cool thanks again!

Comment: I'm a back-end developer, but whenever I'm doing some side project that forces me into the front-end I immediately have to make this decision. In my opinion, both choices are really ugly. Using all kinds of crazy hacks and complexity really makes me cringe. Using a construct for something it wasn't meant for makes me cringe as well. In the end, I always seem to go for the table. It may be ugly, but at least it is dead simple to understand and takes about five seconds to implement. Either way, this is the reason I prefer back end coding - even seemingly simple things have religious wars here.

Answer (score 4):

[This excellent article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts/) on *A List Apart* builds such a layout from scratch, and also contains some interesting links to other articles on the subject, such as [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) (also on ALA).

Comment: Thanks for your tip too, interesting technique.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just set the height of the sidebar to be 100% and it will follow the parent element's height. In the example below its the container element. No matter it's height, sidebar's height will be 100% and therefore always be same height as container.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
      <div id="sidebar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
#wrapper {}
#container {min-height:500px;}  (or whatever you want for the height)
#sidebar {height:100%;}
</style>
```