# Getting the sidebar to behave?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Ok Im working on a site that has a sidebar and a main content section. The site is made using DIV's but the problem Im getting is that the sidebar doesnt stretch vertically with the content div. For example the sidebar has a few links while the content div has alot of stuff I want the sidebar to stretch. Thanks

Comment: can you push some code for better understanding ?

Comment: @sandeep I have a jsFiddle which is easier to understand. http://jsfiddle.net/MQy4Y/

Comment: Have you tried `height:100%` on content and sidebar div and all of their parents? something like `html, body, div {height:100%;}` but more granular and specific.

Comment: It is always good to put some code to get good answers...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194983/html-css-how-to-make-the-sidebar-and-content-follow-each-other this link will give you some hint.

Comment: @rebus That doesn't work it strectches the divs to the screen height but the content overflows out of the divs

Comment: @Sandy Thanks that article helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell` property for this & remove `float` from them. Write like this:

```
#sidebar,#content_box{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/MQy4Y/2/

It's works till IE8  & above.

Comment: Thanks even easier that the other method that Sandeep linked me too.